Firefox favicons for subdirs not working
I am having problems with Firefox bookmark favicons!
 
Example - bookmarks showing same favicon
          
 
Setup:
Two different favicons used on my site -

justinreina.com - justinreina.com/favicon.ico
justinreina.com/lifebook - justinreina.com/lifebook/favicon.ico

 
✅ Status:

These are working for page thumbnails in Firefox/Chrome/Edge
There are working for bookmark thumbnails in Chrome/Edge

 
❌ Problem:

Firefox shows the same justinreina.com/favicon.ico favicon for both sites

 
Debugging:
I try the method to clear bookmarks identified here

SuperUser - Wrong Favicons in Firefox


Cleared out! No favicons present
Open the justinreina.com bookmark to load its favicon
Open the justinreina.com\lifebook bookmark to load its different favicon! Success?
Click on the justinreina.com bookmark, which RESETS BOTH FAVICONS to the justinreina.com favicon 

 
So this is broken, for Firefox see above. Can Firefox show different bookmark favicons located on the same domain?

The effect you want is achieved with a link element in the head section of the html file, something line 

Working on w/Mozilla now - Bookmark favicons for subdir pages not working
